# which of these functions are the same

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

which of these functions are the same?
$$f(x)=(5^{-x})+3 \, ;
g(x)=5^{(3-x)} \, ;
h(x)=-5^{(x-3)}$$
i have already tried a lot of things but none of them shows the same function
Thank you.

Comment: "but none of them shows the same function".  Do any of them show *different* functions?  The *can't* be the same if they are different.

Answer (score 2):

Check each function's value at $0$.

EDIT: Two functions $u$ and $v$ are said to be equal if and only if $u(x)=v(x)$ for all $x$. In particular, if there exists some $x$ so that $u(x)\neq v(x)$, the two functions are not equal.

Comment: yes i tried this.the first function is equaled to 4.the second =125 .and the third =-1/125

Comment: @LedjaNushi um,  those are all three different values.  So.....

Comment: Exactly, "So....."

Comment: So, if I asked you to show that 4 = 125.  How long would you try failed after failed attempt before you conclude..... "Hmm, maybe 4 *doesn't* equal 125"?.... Anyway  if f and g are the same then 4 = 125.  They aren't, so f and g *AREN'T* the same. End of story.  If f and h are the same then 4 =-1/125.  They aren't.  End of story.  If g and h are the same then 125 = -1/125.  They aren't.  They aren't.  That's it.  None of them are the same.

Comment: @fleablood - I know, I'm sorry but I clicked the wrong button from the Review section and I don't know how to undo. My apologies.

Comment: Sorry, I over reacted.  It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with swinging a hammer:

$f(0) = 5^{-0} + 3 = 4$.  $g(0) = 5^{3-0} = 125$.  $h(0) = -5^{0-3}= -\frac 1{125}$.

Last time I checked, $f(0)= 4 \ne 125=g(0)$.  And $f(0)=4 \ne -\frac 1{125}=h(0)$.  $g(0) = 125 \ne -\frac 1{125}=h(0)$.   .... At least that was the case, last time I checked.

No two of those values are equal so no two of the functions are equal.

It's that simple.

Comment: so any of the functions is the same, right?

Comment: How can any of them be the same if they are *ALL* different?????